# ReactJS key attribute type

Tags: reactjs

I can't find the documentation about the allowed types for *key* attribute.
Looks like type *object* is not an option, i'm getting 'duplicate keys warning' in console while  using plain js object as key :

```jsx
var someArray = [{name:1},{name:2}];
{someArray.map(function(o){
    return <div key={o}> {o.name} </div>
    })
}
```

The fiddle is here :   http://jsfiddle.net/iamfuric/gosbgm6q/

Is it a bug or *object* is  unsupported ?

Thanks

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question, you cannot use the object the way you want to use it as it can't be seen as unique. maybe doing something like `{"1": {"name": 1}}` would help, but I don't think it will make sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `key` just needs to be a basic type that can be treated as a hash value to determine uniqueness. So, a string or a number for example. There isn't a built-in JavaScript function on objects like some programming languages have that can return a unique hash value for an object instance.

You'll either need to use an existing unique value, or create something artificially that will remain part of the object's lifetime.

http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/vkfr6wc5/1/

In my example, I've created a simple function that adds a unique property called `_key` to each object if the property doesn't already exist. Then I passed that as the `key` attribute to the component.

```jsx
var Hello = React.createClass({     
    render: function() {
        var someArray = [{name:'name1'},
                         {name:'name2'}];     
         return <div> {someArray.map(function(o){
            unique(o);
            return <div key={o._key}> {o.name} - { o._key} </div>
         });
    }
});

var __unique = 0;
function unique(obj, key) {
    key = key || '_key';
    if(typeof obj === 'undefined' || obj === null) {
        return obj;
    }
    if(!obj[key]) {
        obj[key] = ++__unique;
    }
    return obj;
}

React.render(<Hello key="world" />, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but what is the reason ReactJS team doesn't support === operator  for plain js key objects comparison ?

Comment: Object equality wouldn't always be a valid comparison. Code may have obtained the same "logically equivalent" data as objects via multiple mechanisms, where a simple `object` === `object` wouldn't work. If JavaScript objects had a `getHashCode()` method, then I could see using objects.

Answer (score -5):

I think that it is better to specify the key as a unique id instead of an object.

Because the key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique so you can add an index in your map function and assign it to the key:

```jsx
var someArray = [{name:1},{name:2}];
    {someArray.map(function(o, index){
         return <div key={index}> {o.name} </div>
    })
}
```

Comment: This is very bad advice. Using an index as a key is actually an anti-pattern. Have a look here: https://dev.to/jtonzing/the-significance-of-react-keys---a-visual-explanation--56l7